# Cannot connect to my MYSQL container through SequelPro and through my other PHP container

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm a beginner to docker.
I can login into my mysql container and access the database.
But i cannot access it from my PHP container and also when i try to connect from mysql client(sequelPro).

**PHP DockerFile**

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli && \
    docker-php-ext-install mbstring && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ -- 
    with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/  &&  \
    docker-php-ext-install gd
COPY ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN service apache2 restart
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  mysql:
     image: mysql:5.7
     ports:
         - "4407:3306"
     volumes:
         - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
     environment:
         - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
         - MYSQL_DATABASE=shutterfly
shutterfly:
    build: ./shutterfly
    volumes:
         - ./shutterfly:/var/www/html/
    depends_on:
         - mysql
    restart: always
    links:
         - mysql
    ports:
         - "8000:80"
```

**CodeIgnitor is giving me this error:**

```
Severity: Warning
Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
Line Number: 201
Backtrace:
File: /var/www/html/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php
Line Number: 518
```

In my **Database.php** I have

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => "0.0.0.0",
'database_user' => 'root',
'database_password' => 'root',
'databasename' => 'shutterfly',
'port' => '4407',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Can you let me know what i'm missing?

Comment: I tried "mysql" instead of 0.0.0.0 ('hostname' => "0.0.0.0",) but it did not work. Also tried localhost,127.0.0.1 too, but no luck :(

Comment: oh I was gonna rewrite `'hostname' => "mysql"` as answer...

Comment: ok. please try `docker-compose logs mysql`. how is results?

Comment: Its a list of Notes and Warnings before this mysqld: ready for connections.Warning are like this Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
  'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
  'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
  'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.

Comment: please run `docker-compose exec mysql bash` and run `mysql -u root -proot -h mysql` within mysql containar. can you show mysql command-line after these?

Comment: These 2 are the container running right now                                
  cf7a24425a4f        cishutterfly_shutterfly   "docker-php-entrypoin"   5 hours ago         Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp                cishutterfly_shutterfly_1
7ce8b0827777        mysql:5.7                 "docker-entrypoint.sh"   5 hours ago         Up About an hour    33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4407->3306/tcp   cishutterfly_mysql_1.  So i ran docker exec -ti cishutterfly_mysql_1 bash and i was able to login and also connect to the db using mysql -u root -proot -h mysql.

Comment: mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 3
Server version: 5.7.23 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
mysql>

Comment: sorry i don't have more ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Your port in Database.php should be 3306 and host name should be `mysql`. When docker makes the connection internally using it's networking, you should specify the internal port, not the exposed one.

If you want to use the exposed port 4407, you should use your computer's actual IP address in the hostname. Not localhost/ 0.0.0.0. When you use these from within a docker container, it's localhost to the containers. Not of the host.

Comment: Is the error message same or you get something else?